# Can't query for description from SQL using ADSI

Tags: sql, sql-server, active-directory, adsi

I have a linked server using ADSI. I can successfully query for most attributes except `description`.

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery (ADSI,  
    'SELECT description,sn,givenName
    FROM  ''LDAP://mydomain.com/OU=users,DC=com,DC=mydomain'' 
    WHERE title<>''Virtual'' AND (userAccountControl=''66048'' OR 
    userAccountControl=''512'')') 
ORDER BY sn
```

It throws this error:

```
"Cannot get the data of the row from the OLE DB provider "ADSDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI". Could not convert the data value due to reasons other than sign mismatch or overflow."
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field `description` is multivalued.

See here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675492(v=vs.85).aspx

SQL Server does not support multivalued fields and therefore you won't be able to get that one in your query.